# Верна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Да сколько можно-то уже,эту чертову вещь рекламировать? Запятая верна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна. Обычное простое предложение, ничем не осложненное.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет оснований для постановки запятой